# Use a variable created in get_header to calculate stuff in wp_footer

Tags: hooks, globals

i am trying to create a small time tester that loads at get_header hook and the using the value does something in wp_footer...

- i have tried using global $var
- i tried putting the global var inside the function
- i tried attaching it to the wp_head instead of get_header

**Here is a simplefied ver of the the code:**

```
 // LOAD TIME CHECKER
function start_timer() {
    global $time_start;
    $time_start = microtime(true);
}
add_action('wp_head', 'start_timer', 1);

if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    function end_time() {
        echo '
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div id="queryTime" style="position: fixed; bottom: 30px; left: 30px;">
                <ul class="li"><span class="label label-success fs13">Start Time: '.$time_start.'</span></ul>
                <ul class="li"><span class="label label-success fs13">Query Took: '.number_format( microtime(true) - $time_start, 10).'</span></ul>
            </div>
        ';
    }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'end_time', 100);
}
```

Can anyone offer a pointer with a bit of explenation? trying to grasp what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redeclare the variable in your end_time() and also you don't need the user to be logged in.. You can try the below answer.

```
// LOAD TIME CHECKER
function start_timer() {

    global $time_start;
    $time_start = microtime(true);
}
add_action('wp_head', 'start_timer', 1);

function end_time() {
      //try redeclaring the var 
       global $time_start;
    echo '
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div id="queryTime" style="position: fixed; bottom: 30px; left: 30px;">
            <ul class="li"><span class="label label-success fs13">Start Time: '.$time_start.'</span></ul>
            <ul class="li"><span class="label label-success fs13">Query Took: '.number_format( microtime(true) - $time_start, 10).'</span></ul>
        </div>
    ';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'end_time', 100);
```

Comment: WORKS! so i just needed to declare the var inside the desired func ;) thanks a lot mate.